# format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Tags: c

So Im just starting out coding in C. I was coding this custom squeeze function and I have an error i cannot explain. The goal is to get the letter 'c' out of the code. When I try to compile I get a warning I have provided in the title. How did did '**argv' become 'int' ?

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int i,j;
for(i=j=0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
    if(argv[1][i] != 'c')
        argv[1][j++] = argv[1][i];
argv[1][j] = '\0';
for(i=0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf("%s", argv[1][i]);
}
```

Comment: If the goal is to get a "letter", why are you using format `%s`, which works with *strings*, not with single letters?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
printf("%s", argv[1][i]);
```

to

```
printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
```

**or better, remove the last for:**

```
 printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`**argv` is a `char`. But when you pass a `char` value to a variadic function as one of the `...` arguments (e.g. `printf`), it is automatically converted to `int`. That's how `**argv` became an `int`.

In any case `%s` is not immediately suitable for printing individual letters. You want to print a single `char`, apparently. That's done with `%c` format.